# Convert to float and pad left with zero on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I need to convert to float and pad left with zero in SQL Server.

I need in this format `####.##`.

For example:

```
2.23   ->  0002.23
123.3  ->  0123.30
12.65  ->  0012.65
34     ->  0034.00
```

I tried this:

```
cast(Weight as decimal(6, 2))
```

and also this:

```
REPLACE(STR(Weight, 6), SPACE(1), '0')
```

and this:

```
REPLACE(STR(cast(Weight as decimal(6,2)), 6), SPACE(1), '0')
```

But they do not work - I got `5.00` or `000005` and I need `0005.00`.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If SQL Server 2012+, FORMAT() is an option.

```
Select format(123.3,'0000.00')
```

Returns

```
0123.30
```

`Format()` has some nice features, but not known for its performance

Comment: Every time I used to forgot this `FORMAT` :/ +1

Comment: @Gold Happy it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about how to achieve this mathematically but here is one way by string manipulation

```
DECLARE @num  NUMERIC(22, 2) = '2.23', 
        @temp VARCHAR(100) 

SET @temp = Cast(@num AS VARCHAR(100)) 

SELECT RIGHT('000'+LEFT(@temp, Charindex('.', @temp)-1), 4) 
       + LEFT(Substring(@temp, Charindex('.', @temp), Len(@temp))+'0', 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
CREATE FUNCTION [usf_PadFloat] ( @InputNum Float, @PadLen Integer )
RETURNS varchar(25)
/****************************************************************************************
-- Returns current time if null
--   (No it doesn't I just lack at changing comments when I reuse code)

select dbo.[usf_PadFloat](28.1273, 4)
select dbo.[usf_PadFloat](17, 4)
select dbo.[usf_PadFloat](2.23, 4)
select dbo.[usf_PadFloat](123.3, 4)
select dbo.[usf_PadFloat](12.65, 4)
select dbo.[usf_PadFloat](34, 4)

****************************************************************************************/
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @Retval varchar(25)

        Select @InputNum = Round(@InputNum,2)

        Select @Retval = cast(@InputNum as varchar(25))

        if charindex('.',@Retval) = 0
            Select @Retval += '.00'

        While charindex('.',Reverse(@Retval)) <> 3 and len(@Retval) < 100 --just n case.
          Select @Retval += '0'

        select @Retval = Right(replicate('0',@padlen+3) + @Retval, @Padlen+3)

        return @Retval
    END
```